# Scrolling issue with Dual Screen or external monitor (Laptop) Microsoft Excel 2013

Tags: microsoft-excel, multiple-monitors, scrolling, microsoft-excel-2013

There is a peculiar **intermittent** problem with Microsoft excel on one of my users' computers, when selecting a range of cells that is out of the visible area by clicking and dragging, you would expect the selector to automatically scroll horizontally along the spread sheet selecting as it goes, however with a dual screen or external monitor attached this doesn't seem to work at all. It works fine on 2010 version of office but not on 2013...

Is this a bug that Microsoft have yet to discover/ rectify or is there a way in which I can allow for Scrolling along the excel spread sheet for selecting data in excel 2013?

**[EDIT]**

I have found now that this problem is exclusive to one certain Excel document I have tried another document and it seems to work.

Comment: Does the window extend across the two screens or beyond the visible portion of the external?

Comment: no its on the main laptop monitor but it scrolls to the side in which the mouse crosses over to the other monitor...

Comment: What other troubleshooting have you performed? Does it happen going right from the left screen and left from the right screen? What about right from the right scren or left from the left screen?

Comment: I've tested on other documents and I've discovered it is Exclusive to this document that my user is working on

Comment: So it's a specific workbook's issue then? Might be built in somewhere. Without additional information, unfortunately, this question cannot be solved.

Comment: @Raystafarian Yeah its very difficult to diagnose, it seems to have fixed itself but I just want to know what would be the possible cause of it refusing to scroll when selecting. it goes to the edge of the visible area and then jumps back to only selecting two columns when going outside the worksheet (onto the scroll bar as if to make it scroll horizontally along the page.) Hope this provides more detail.

Comment: @Raystafarian I am also selecting all cells in the columns by dragging from the top (A) along the letters.